# Google Maps suddenly couldn't load normally

Tags: javascript, c++

I call Google map through JavaScript and open it directly in the browser, which can be opened normally. Call Google maps through the WebBrowser in the C + + program, which can be opened normally before(have Prompt for changing browser: ”The browser you are using is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Designer changing your browser.”  But the map can be displayed normally); However, it has not been opened normally since last week (only the prompt to change the browser, but the map is not displayed). Why? Or other possible reasons?

Comment: probably a bug on line 37 of the code

Comment: line 37 of the code?

Comment: Please show a [mre], what web browser are you using? I'm guessing it doesn't support the minimum required JavaScript standard version required by Google maps

Comment: it was a guess - one day I'll be right